# Rossler - Mutually Coupled Oscillator

Tags: matlab, plot

I know how to plot Rossler System for the general equations,

[image]

In my MATLAB code for plotting this, I used something like this,

```
f = @(t,y) [-y(2)-y(3); y(1)+a*y(2); b + y(3).*(y(1)-c) ];
plot(Y1(:,1), Y1(:,2),'r-');
```

In the below case, there is a coupling factor and it is plotted for a line. I don't know how to give this equation in MATLAB. I'm not able to interpret what is Y1,2 means.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't have a programing problem, but a mathematical one, as you don't know what they are.

From the incomplete part that you show x,y,z seems like 2x2 matrixes.

Comment: I assumed it to be 2x2 but I don't know how to give these three equations in MATLAB. Is it supposed to be something like this? -y(1,2)-z(1,2) + C*(x(2,1) - x(1,2))

Comment: Yes, the `y(1,2)` refers to first line, second column of the variable y. 
If is that that you mean.